# alternative to combined comparison operator (<=>) in .sort

Tags: ruby, spaceship-operator

I know that if I want to sort an array in descending order I have to do the following:

```
array.sort!{|a,b| b <=> a}
```

However, if I want to avoid using the "spaceship" (<=>) operator, I would intuitively think that I can do the following, but I receive an error when I run it on repl.it:

```
array.sort!{|a, b| 
    if b < a 
        return -1
    elsif b > a
        return 1
    else
        return 0 
    end
}
```

The error is this:

```
(eval):4: (eval):4: unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
from (eval):0:in `sort!'
from (eval):0
```

Someone please help me!

P.S. I am very new to Ruby. I am just going through the lessons on Codecademy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` returns from a method. It can only be used inside a method. There is no method in your code, therefore you get an error … and even if there *were* a method, the code wouldn't do what you want, because `return` returns from the method, not the block.

To return a value from a block, use `next`:

```
array.sort! {|a, b| 
  if b < a 
    next -1
  elsif b > a
    next 1
  else
    next 0 
  end
}
```

However, unlike in C, `if`/`then`/`else` is an expression in Ruby, not a statement. (Actually, *everything* is an expression in Ruby, there are *no* statements.) This means that everything, including a conditional expression, returns a value. For `if`/`then`/`else` the value being returned is the one from the branch that was taken.

So, instead of returning from each of the branches separately, we can just return the vlue of the whole `if` expression:

```
array.sort! {|a, b| 
  next if b < a 
    -1
  elsif b > a
    1
  else
    0 
  end
}
```

And since the return value of a block (just like the return value of a method) is implicitly the last value evaluated inside the block, we can just say:

```
array.sort! {|a, b| 
  if b < a 
    -1
  elsif b > a
    1
  else
    0 
  end
}
```

`next` is mostly useful to break out early of a block in a guard-clause style or to flatten a deeply nested conditional:

```
array.sort! {|a, b| 
  next -1 if b < a 
  next  1 if b > a
        0 
}
```

Note that `case` would probably more appropriate than `if` here:

```
array.sort! {|a, b| 
  case
  when b < a 
    -1
  when b > a
    1
  else
    0 
  end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word `return` so your code looks like

```
array.sort!{|a, b| 
  if b < a 
    -1
  elsif b > a
    1
  else
    0 
  end
}
```

Comment: Why is that though? Aren't you technically "returning" those values?

Comment: `return` break the iteration.

Comment: ah. And besides the whole if/elsif/else are just part of the block right. So the block does not act so much as a function as it does as a syntax for the method .sort -- telling it how to deal with the two elements "a" and "b", correct?

Comment: Pretty much. Search the web for "proc vs block vs lambda".